# How to solve "/dev/nvmeen1p8: clean, 462711/3203072 files, 8713515/12800256 blocks" error during boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, boot-repair

This message is popping when I boot Ubuntu:

```
/dev/nvmeen1p8: clean, 462711/3203072 files, 8713515/12800256 blocks
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: That is a NOTICE not an error. and as such not a problem. The next action is. What did you do before the boot stopped working? Generally only 2 things bork a boot: hardware errors and a graphics card driver problem.